# Run script through launch agent is failed

Tags: terminal, applescript, launchd, screen-sharing

I try to run the next script through LaunchAgent:

```
on run argv
    set current_path to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
    set common to load script (current_path & "common.scpt")
    set screenSharingApp to "Screen Sharing"

    try
        if application screenSharingApp is running then do shell script "killall '" & screenSharingApp & "'"
    end try
    repeat until application screenSharingApp is not running
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    tell application screenSharingApp
        launch
        activate
    end tell

end run
```

But always I get this error: execution error: `Screen Sharing got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)`

If I run the same script through Script Editor or Terminal is running OK.

What can it be? Why does it not work?

My plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.myapp</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/user1/Desktop/stderr.log</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/user1/Desktop/stdout.log</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
            <string>/Users/user1/Desktop/1.scpt</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>300</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: How exactly do you run it through a LaunchAgent? - Normally you would require a logged in user to be able to comunicate with a GUI app like that.

Comment: @klanomath added

Comment: @jksoegaard I run through Terminal: sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myapp.plist

Comment: I assume it *does* work if you run `osascript /Users/user1/Desktop/1.scpt` directly from Terminal?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, it does. It works in ScriptEditor also

Comment: Well, you could use `pkill "Screen Sharing"` instead which doesn't care if the process isn't running.

Comment: @klanomath It doesn't work. It doesn't open window of Screen Sharing

Comment: @klanomath I know it. I mean even "popup is asking for an address" doesn't appear.

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.3

Answer (score 1):

My recommendations:

1. Move anything to neutral ground:

   This removes the launch agent from the launchd database:

   ```
   sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myapp.plist
   sudo launchctl remove com.myapp
   ```

   Move the .scpt file:

   ```
   sudo mv ~/Desktop/common.scpt /usr/local/bin/
   ```

   Remove unneeded std* files:

   ```
   rm ~/Desktop/stdout.log
   rm ~/Desktop/stderr.log
   ```

   Modify /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myapp.plist with `sudo nano /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myapp.plist` accordingly:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>Disabled</key>
       <false/>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>com.myapp</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
           <string>/usr/local/bin/common.scpt</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
       <string>/tmp/com.myapp.stderr</string>
       <key>StandardOutPath</key>
       <string>/tmp/com.myapp.stdout</string>
       <key>StartInterval</key>
       <integer>300</integer>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
2. Increase application kill check delay in the script:

   ```
    ...
    repeat until application screenSharingApp is not running
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    ...
   ```
3. Load the plist:

   ```
   sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myapp.plist
   ```

---

Check that no older "Screen Sharing" app is present on another volume and linked in the launch services database!

Comment: It doesn't help me. I marked that simple restart can help me, BUT only for first running. I also tried through crontab, and I get the same behaviour

Comment: @Rougher Fixed some errors in my plist (had a wrong StandardErrorPath: /tmp/com.myapp.**stdout** in my previous version). I tested all my recommendations again in a 10.15 vm and I indeed get the same error after loading the plist (*... Application isn’t running.*) but after a reboot it works without **any** error.